# Why does creating a Path in hadoop cause a NullPointerException?

Tags: java, hadoop

I'm new to hadoop and trying to create a file in HDFS from within the mapper of a map-reduce job.

The following code produces a NullPointerException in the last line:

```
DistributedFileSystem dfs = new DistributedFileSystem();
Path parent = dfs.getWorkingDirectory();
Path child = new Path("bar.txt");
Path path = new Path(parent, child);
```

What am I doing wrong and why is this causing an Exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely `parent` is null because `getWorkingDirectory` returned null.